# Prevent access to mobile photo library

Tags: lightning-aura-components, apexinputfile

my intent is to prevent users from accessing pictures in their camera library of their mobile phone while uploading images to Salesforce. I have run out of luck so thought will check in here to see if there are any options to prevent access to the mobile camera/photo library from a lightning component.

I have a lightning component where I tried using the below three options but did not find any option to prevent access to the mobile photo library.

- lightning:fileUpload
- lightning:input type="file"
- input type="file"

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Prevent access to their library/gallery as opposed to what, uploading fresh images?

Comment: @sfdcfox I would like to force the users to use a custom Android app that is built specifically for taking images. The reason is that we don't want images to be stored on end user's mobile phones so by forcing the user to pick an image from only the custom Android app and not the mobile phone's library, it will ensure that the user is always using the custom app.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MySalesforce product and other ways of managing via MDM.

Comment: The community is built using partner central template and as of now, templates are not available on Salesforce1 (MySalesforce).

Answer (score 0):

you can limit the allowed file extensions with the accept attribute - when you set `accept=".txt"` the user shouldn't be able to add photos from his album

Comment: Yes that is possible though it does not prevent me from using a photo from the mobile photo library.